# Is it possible select submenu with [Tab] key only? (css only)

Tags: html, css, focus, accessibility

Is it possible select (activate) submenu in ul/ol-styled menu with [Tab] key only, so the submenu will be visible?

I tried using :focus pseudo-class

```
ul
    li
        a:focus
        +
        ul
            li
                a ...
```

and with submenu selected:

```
ul
    li
        a (?)
        +
        ul
            li
                a:focus ...
```

But I can't select active node with CSS

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/DKvH2/

Comment: You essentially need the tab to be on the `a` element, but apply css to the parent ul element. This isn't possible with pure CSS, i would suggest rejigging your code so applying css to the `a` element makes it come into view

Comment: So, is the solution to create nested **a** tags? This will be wrong, Isn`t it?

Comment: No, you need to do for example `a { display: none; }` and then `a:focus { display: block; }`. Throwing that in probably won't work immediately but I think thats the best way of doing it, as you can't style a parent depending on if you are focused on its child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the complete submenue to be visible when a submenue-item has focus, I don't see a way without Javascript.
If it is enough for you, if just the focused element is visible, you could try something like this:

```
.links > li:not(:hover) li a:focus {
    left: 9999em;
    position: relative;
}
```

This would move the focused element back where it should be, if this didn't already happen via :hover-pseudo-class.

http://jsfiddle.net/DKvH2/1/

Comment: Better then nothing :)
Thanks, but I'll leave question open.

Comment: There are no other solutions found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May **tabindex** is work for you.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="links">
        <li tabindex="1">
            <a href="#i1">Item 1</a>
        </li>
            <li tabindex="2">
            <a href="#i2">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="#i2-1">Item 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#i2-1">Item 2.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.links > li:focus a + ul{top:auto}
```

I have created an example this http://jsfiddle.net/DKvH2/3/

Read this http://css-tricks.com/expanding-images-html5/